# How can I reference object data within an object function?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a simple tic tac toe game to learn and practice JavaScript OOP and am having some difficulties.

I would like to reference the `game.turn` value when firing the `game.handleClick` function. I know that using the `this` keyword references the scope of the thing being called, and in `handleClick`, the `this` refers to the `game-tile-x` being clicked. How can I reference object values that are outside of the 'handleClick' function scope?

Any help would be deeply appreciated!

```html
<div id="game-board">
    <div id="game-tile-1" class="game-tile"></div>
    <!-- divs 2-8 -->
    <div id="game-tile-9" class="game-tile"></div>
</div>
```

```
function Game() {
    this.tiles = document.getElementsByClassName('game-tile'),
    this.turn = 0;

    this.init = function() {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.tiles.length; i++) {
            // reset game tiles
            this.tiles[i].innerHTML = '';

            // setup event listeners
            this.tiles[i].addEventListener('click', this.handleClick);
        }
    };
    this.handleClick = function() {
        let id = parseInt(this.id.replace('game-tile-', ''));
        console.log(id); // returns 0, 1, 2, etc.
        console.log(this.turn); // returns undefined
    };
}

let game = new Game();
game.init();
```

Comment: it's common to set a variable to `this` so you can reference it later when it's out of scope. ex: `let ctx = this; this.init = function(){....ctx.tiles[i]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here a basic solution

```
function Game() {
    this.tiles = document.getElementsByClassName('game-tile'),
    this.turn = 0;

    this.init = function() {
        let tile;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.tiles.length; i++) {
            tile = this.tiles[i];
            // reset game tiles
            tile.innerHTML = '';

            // setup event listeners
            // don't mix this for the node & this for the game
            // let's bind the context to the game, and the first param to the tile
            tile.addEventListener('click', handleClick.bind(this, tile));
        }
    };

    function handleClick(tile) {
        let id = parseInt(tile.id.replace('game-tile-', ''));
        console.log(id); // returns 0, 1, 2, etc.
        console.log(this.turn); // returns undefined
    };
}

let game = new Game();
game.init();
```

Comment: This solution works perfect for me! Would you be able to explain the difference between an object function with and without the `this` keyword? Example: `this.myFunction = function() {}` versus `function myFunction() {}`?

Comment: Function Declaration: `function foo() {}`
- declares the function in the function scope WITH its implementation
- makes it directly available from the top of the scope ("hoisting")
- the `this` context is not defined but can be assigned on call. If I used `var foo = function() {}` (function expression), `foo` would be declared and hoisted but it would remain undefined until the expression is evaluated. Assign a function (declaration or expression) to an object property (`this.func = foo` or `obj.func = foo`) AND call it FROM it (`obj.func()`), the `this` context will reference the obj.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a curried function, and call the outer one with the game instance (`this`) then you can use it inside:

```
 this.tiles[i].addEventListener('click', this.handleClick(this));

 //...

this.handleClick = function(game) {
 return function() {
    let id = parseInt(this.id.replace('game-tile-', ''));
    console.log(id); // returns 0, 1, 2, etc.
    console.log(game.turn); 
 };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript's `this` value is determined at call time and how it's called. When you click on a tile, the browser reacts by invoking `handleClick`. The `this` value is usually the element clicked. `this.turn` is `undefined` because your element does not have a property `turn`.

What you do is store the value of `this` in a separate variable within scope. This way, you can refer to `this` without using the keyword `this`.

```
function Game() {
  // The value of "this" in a constructor is the instance of the constructor.
  // We store a reference of "this" in variable "foo" (could be anything really).
  const foo = this

  this.handleClick = function() {
    // Use "instance" instead of "this".
    console.log(foo.turn)
  };
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `function.bind()` to bind the value of `this` (i.e. create an identical function whose `this` value is already defined ahead of time, instead of at call time).

```
function Game() {
  this.init = function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.tiles.length; i++) {
      // Tell the browser that when it calls handleClick, the value
      // of "this" is the one we provided in bind.
      this.tiles[i].addEventListener('click', this.handleClick.bind(this))
    }
  }
  this.handleClick = function() {
    console.log(this.turn); // returns undefined
  };
}

const game = new Game()
game.init()
```

Note that this approach also relies on how `init()` is called, because it also determines what `init`'s `this` value is. If I call it differently, like the following:

```
const game = new Game()
const init = game.init()
init()
```

`init`'s `this` will be `window` (normal mode) or `undefined` (strict mode), which will cause the binding of `handleClick` to use that value.

Comment: The second version won't work for the usecase shown by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways you can do this, either by saving `this` to a variable you will use later (we call this a closure):

for instance:

```
const self = this;
this.handleClick = function() {
    const id = parseInt(this.id.replace('game-tile-', ''));
};
```

Or by calling bind, which will bind the `this` object of the function to the `this` of the current scope:

```
this.handleClick = function() {
    const id = parseInt(this.id.replace('game-tile-', ''));
};
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
```

PS:

If you can use ES6 Arrow functions:

```
this.handleClick = () => {
    // this will point to the scope where the function is declared
}
```

If you can use ES6 classes:

```
class Game(){
    constructor(){
        this.tiles = document.getElementsByClassName('game-tile'),
        this.turn = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.tiles.length; i++) {
        // reset game tiles
        this.tiles[i].innerHTML = '';

        // setup event listeners
        this.tiles[i].addEventListener('click', this.handleClick);
    }

    handleClick = () => {
        let id = parseInt(this.id.replace('game-tile-', ''));
        console.log(id); // returns 0, 1, 2, etc.
        console.log(this.turn); // returns undefined
    }
}
```

It is better to use ES6 syntax because it is easier to understand for both the reader and the machine. If you are worried about browser compability, use a transpiler like [BabelJS](https://babeljs.io/)

Comment: The second way won't work as the OP wants to access the clicked element too.